# Setup Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I am having trouble with setting up
**Remote Desktop Manager** in Windows Server 2012 R2

If you could help me with figuring out the issue in my setup.

Picture which includes the error.

[Server Manager Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOZGi.jpg)

Thanks Guys

Comment: What have you done so far in order to try and fix the error? Pasting the error into Google goes a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the server to the server pool, Then try again. also you can type mstsc.exe /admin then the name server you want in the command prompt and see how it goes. Good luck